# Google Map API Search Filter

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm trying to filter search box only 3 districts in Turkey which are "Sarıyer", "Beşiktaş", "Şişli". I did if condition for long_name in address_components but it doesn't work properly.

I thought that by writing this condition if user search these 3 districts marker will set on the map. Or if user search another place it will appear popup message "You can only search in these 3 districts"

How can i filter search box as this

```
    var addCom1 = place.address_components[0].long_name;
    var addCom2 = place.address_components[1].long_name;
    var addCom3 = place.address_components[2].long_name;
    var addCom4 = place.address_components[3].long_name;
    var addCom5 = place.address_components[4].long_name;
    var addCom6 = place.address_components[5].long_name;

    if(addCom1 == "Şişli" || addCom1 == "Beşiktaş" || addCom1 == "Sarıyer" ||
    addCom2 == "Şişli" || addCom2 == "Beşiktaş" || addCom2 == "Sarıyer" ||
    addCom3 == "Şişli" || addCom3 == "Beşiktaş" || addCom3 == "Sarıyer" ||
    addCom4 == "Şişli" || addCom4 == "Beşiktaş" || addCom4 == "Sarıyer" ||
    addCom5 == "Şişli" || addCom5 == "Beşiktaş" || addCom5 == "Sarıyer" ||
    addCom6 == "Şişli" || addCom6 == "Beşiktaş" || addCom6 == "Sarıyer"){

     // Here i need set the marker

    }else{

     // Pop up messsage "You can only search these 3 districts"

    }
```

---

```
function initAutocomplete() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 41.1810741, lng: 29.0094592},
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap
    });

    options = {
      language: 'tr',
      types: ['(cities)'],
      componentRestrictions: { country: "tr" }
    };

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, options);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);


    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markers = [];
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      // Clear out the old markers.
      markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      markers = [];

      // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      places.forEach(function(place) {
        if (!place.geometry) {
          console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
        }

        var icon = {
          url: place.icon,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };


        var addCom1 = place.address_components[0].long_name;
        var addCom2 = place.address_components[1].long_name;
        var addCom3 = place.address_components[2].long_name;
        var addCom4 = place.address_components[3].long_name;
        var addCom5 = place.address_components[4].long_name;
        var addCom6 = place.address_components[5].long_name;

        if(addCom1 == "Şişli" || addCom1 == "Beşiktaş" || addCom1 == "Sarıyer" ||
        addCom2 == "Şişli" || addCom2 == "Beşiktaş" || addCom2 == "Sarıyer" ||
        addCom3 == "Şişli" || addCom3 == "Beşiktaş" || addCom3 == "Sarıyer" ||
        addCom4 == "Şişli" || addCom4 == "Beşiktaş" || addCom4 == "Sarıyer" ||
        addCom5 == "Şişli" || addCom5 == "Beşiktaş" || addCom5 == "Sarıyer" ||
        addCom6 == "Şişli" || addCom6 == "Beşiktaş" || addCom6 == "Sarıyer"){

          // Create a marker for each place.
          markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
          }));


        }


        // console.log(place);
        $(".pin-address").text(place.formatted_address);

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          // Only geocodes have viewport.
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      });

      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
```

Comment: If you need user to search for 3 items only , why you are not using DropDownList with those 3 items as options ?

Comment: Instead of typing those district names over and over again, you really should define a function like `function isGoodDistrict(s) { return s === "Şişli" || s === "Beşiktaş" || s === "Sarıyer"}`.

Comment: I can't use dropdown list because user should write a street name or a place name but only in there 3 places

Comment: There is no easy way to restrict search box to certain administrative area. The feature request exists for a long time: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822067. At the moment a workaround is using place autocomplete with strict bounds, something similar to the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48444166/5140781